# User Objects Dialog box - Doesn't opens up (Business Object)

Tags: business-objects

In business Objects, When I click the User Objects icon in a query panel for a universe, the User Objects dialog box doesnt opens up, however, i checked with other universe, there user objects dialog opens up.

I am not sure of what exactly the parameter of the universe in Designer, enables this feature in Business Objects. Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the universe.udo file is corrupted.

So, Delete the universe.udo files from the universe folder i.e, under "Document & Settings\Application Data\BusinessObjects\Universe

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is good, but I've got a couple of extra bits of information:

1) I'm using BO XI Release 2, and the path to the .udo file is as follows:
C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application Data\Business Objects\Business Objects 11.5\Universes

2) The name of the .udo file is given by the name of the universe with a .udo extension.  Thus if the universe is called "Housing Repairs" then the name of the user objects file will be 'Housing Repairs.udo'.

Hope this helps.